# VirtualBox host only adapter has no address

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have trouble setting up VirtualBox host only adapter on Arch Linux.

The output of `ip addr` is:

```
5: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My VBox settings:

[image: adapter setting]

Guest OSs can comunicate between each other using host only adapter with ip addresses received from Virtual Box DHCP server but the communication between guest OS and host OS does not work on either side.

Comment: Do you have more than one guest?

Answer (score 5):

A user posted a very [similar](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=202381) problem on the Arch forums. He solved it by installing `net-tools`. A quote from his post:

> Apparently Virtual Box uses ifconfig rather than ip for setting up the
>   network, just installing net-tools solved the issue.

So, try that simple solution first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a website that has commands to assign your machine to a IP address. Look through some of the commands on this website and maybe it will help you in your case.

http://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-command-examples/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why your `vboxnet0` network has not been assigned an IP address: on my system, given the **same** connection details on the *Adapter settings* mask, `vboxnet0` appears with its proper address.

However, there is nothing wrong in assigning one manually: issue

```
 sudo ip addr add 192.168.56.1/24 dev vboxnet0
```

and now you may check whether the host-to-guest connectivity thru this interface has been restored; to do so, remember to bring down on the guests, at least temporarily, all other interfaces so that you are sure you are using vboxnet0 instead of any other interface.